# iphone app crash bad access exception DataDetectorsCore processToken

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, nsoperationqueue

My iphone app is crashing on ios 7.0 iphone 5s on client device i can't figure out what is wrong with it, I am using crashlytics for crash reporting.
Crashlytics reporting crash due to bad access on thread #9 DataDetectorsCore processToken

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x17023e120
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000620a51e24

0 DataDetectorsCore processToken + 400

1 DataDetectorsCore _DDScannerHandleState + 344

2 DataDetectorsCore _DDScannerHandleState + 344

3 DataDetectorsCore _DDScannerHandleState + 400

4 DataDetectorsCore _DDScannerHandleState + 400

5 DataDetectorsCore _DDScannerHandleState + 400

6 DataDetectorsCore _DDScannerHandleState + 400

7 DataDetectorsCore DDScannerScanQuery + 456

8 DataDetectorsUI   -[DDOperation main] + 240

9 Foundation    -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 644

10 Foundation   __NSOQSchedule_f + 76

11 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_client_callout + 16

12 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 152

13 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_client_callout + 16

14 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 400

15 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76

16 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread + 356
```

Full crash report:
http://crashes.to/s/e069d75fec9

Comment: Hello, I have similar issue. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't find any thing.