# iOS: I am getting a crash called "DataDetectorsCore processToken"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, crashlytics

This crash has been asked on stackoverflow before here [iphone app crash bad access exception DataDetectorsCore processToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741835/iphone-app-crash-bad-access-exception-datadetectorscore-processtoken), but no one gave an answer. Can someone please help me out here. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. Here is my raw data given from crashlytic.

```
Thread : com.crashlytics.analytics.high-priority
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3927fad4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x391ccde5 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 176
2  UIKit                          0x30d0bba3 _addBackgroundTask + 558
3  UIKit                          0x30d151a7 -[UIApplication    beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:] + 14
4  MyApp                        0x0014652b -[CLSAnalyticsController maintainSessionFragments:]
5  MyApp                        0x001463b3 -[CLSAnalyticsController maintainSessionFragmentsIgnoringError]
6  MyApp                        0x00143ceb -[CLSAnalyticsController handlePriorityTriggeredMaintainSessionFragmentForEvent:]
7  MyApp                        0x00143fc3 __35-[CLSAnalyticsController logEvent:]_block_invoke
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x391c70af _dispatch_client_callout + 22
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x391cb8f3 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 26
10 MyApp                        0x00143b89 -[CLSAnalyticsController dispatchToQueue:asynchronous:block:]
11 MyApp                       0x00143f07 -[CLSAnalyticsController logEvent:]
12 MyApp                      0x00143c5b -[CLSAnalyticsController  applicationLifecycleEvent:]
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2e4fde71 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2e471ab1 _CFXNotificationPost + 1720
15 Foundation                     0x2ee57ec5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
16 UIKit                          0x30d25fd5 -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 460
17 UIKit                          0x30cc5b4b -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3466
18 UIKit                          0x30cc4cfd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
19 UIKit                          0x30d2a321 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 664
20 GraphicsServices               0x3317e76d _PurpleEventCallback + 608
21 CoreFoundation                 0x2e506f1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2e5063e7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
23 CoreFoundation                 0x2e504bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 630
24 CoreFoundation                 0x2e46f471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
25 CoreFoundation                 0x2e46f253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
26 GraphicsServices               0x3317d2eb GSEventRunModal + 138
27 UIKit                          0x30d24845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
28 MyApp                        0x000617e7 main (main.m:16)
```

Comment: Have you tried posting this on the crashlytics forums? And have you updated the SDK to the latest version?